# Connecting to multiple REST services using angularjs controllers not linking

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, ng-controller

I am trying to connect to several REST services through different controllers on angularjs but after one connects the others wont

Here is the REST service that is connected through a controller.js file

```
angular.module("itsBooking").controller("bookingController", function ($scope, $http) {


$scope.init = function () {                                                       
    $http.get("http://webteach_net.hallam.shu.ac.uk/acesjas/api/booking/")           
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.bookings = response;
        })
        .error(function (error) {                                                  
            $scope.errorMessage = error;
        });
};

$scope.init(); 
});
```

And here is the one currently not connecting. The link is working so i'm not sure what i'm doing.

```
angular.module("itsVehicle").controller("vehicleController", function ($scope, $http) {



$scope.init = function () {
    $http.get("http://webteach_net.hallam.shu.ac.uk/acesjas/api/vehicle/") 
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.cars = response;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.errorMessage = error; 
        });

};

$scope.init(); 
});
```

Here is the html that would display the one that is not currently connecting

```
<div ng-controller="vehicleController">
    <form>
        <p>Search for Vehicles <input type="text" ng-model="search"></p>
    </form>
    <p>
        Here are your current vehicles
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Capacity</th>
            <th>Driver</th>
            <th>Registration</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:search">
            <td>{{car.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{car.Make}}</td>
            <td>{{car.Capacity}}</td>
            <td>{{car.Driver}}</td>
            <td>{{car.Registration}}</td>
            <td>{{car.Model}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table> <br />
    </div>
```

I have modules for each controller and a js to link all the modules together

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
SM

Comment: Could you please specify which module is instantiated inside `ng-app=` of your `index.html` file?

Comment: I've tried your code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p2hybc4s/2/ 
You might be having CORS issues: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webteach_net.hallam.shu.ac.uk/acesjas/api/vehicle/' from origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.